# Use if/else statement in pandas groupby and agg funcion

Tags: python, group-by, aggregate

Let's consider this dataFrame below

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('Bike', 'Kawasaki', 130 , 186),
               ('Bike', 'Ducati Panigale' , 135 , 202),
               ('Car', 'Bugatti Chiron' , 461 , 304), 
               ('Car', 'Jaguar XJ220', 472 , 210),
               ('Bike', 'Lightning LS-218' , 137 , 218), 
               ('Car', 'Hennessey Venom GT' , 523 , 270),
               ('Bike', 'BMW S1000RR' , 174 , 188)],
              columns =('Type', 'Name', 'Length' ,'top_speed(mph)'))
```

[image: df]

What i'ld like to do is compute min, max, mean, median and std for Length and top speed but with an If/Else condition for each numerical variable.

This is what i do now:

```
df.groupby(["Type"]).agg(
{
    "Length": ["max", "min", "mean", "median", "std"],
    "top_speed(mph)": ["max", "min", "mean", "median", "std"],
},
axis=1,
)
```

[image: groupby - agg]

I'ld like to compute Length min, max etc `if Type == Bike else None` and compute top_speed min, max etc `if Type == Car else None`. I know we can use a lambda function but in the case we need ton compute one thing, here i have to compute 5 values for each

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
dfs = []
for t in df["Type"].unique():
    x = df[df["Type"] == t].describe()
    # remove/rename rows here as appropriate
    # ...
    dfs.append(x.assign(Type=t).set_index("Type", append=True).unstack(level=0))

x = pd.concat(dfs)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
      Length                                                           top_speed(mph)                                                         
         25%    50%     75% count    max        mean    min        std            25%    50%    75% count    max        mean    min        std
Type                                                                                                                                          
Bike  133.75  136.0  146.25   4.0  174.0  144.000000  130.0  20.215506          187.5  195.0  206.0   4.0  218.0  198.500000  186.0  14.821156
Car   466.50  472.0  497.50   3.0  523.0  485.333333  461.0  33.080709          240.0  270.0  287.0   3.0  304.0  261.333333  210.0  47.595518
```